# Is the "Cast" functionality Miracast or Chromecast?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, chromecast, miracast

When I go to *Settings -> Display -> Cast*, check "Enable wireless display" (no idea why I have to do that) and connect to a display, will it use Chromecast protocol (over Wifi) or will it use Miracast protocol (separate direct Wifi connection)?

Or does it support both and chooses depending on the receiver? Then let's assume the receiver is a Chromecast.

Comment: The "Cast" functionality should always be Chromecast (however as some manufacturer heavily modify Android there may be some devices where this is different). Up to Android 6 there was a "Screen Mirroring" functionality which should have based on MiraCast (according what I have read).

Comment: I just remember that the "Cast" functionality works with a Netgear PTV3000 (Miracast) on both my OnePlus 2 (Android 6) and a Xiaomi Mi A2 lite (Android 9). So unless that same menu can *also* cast to a Chromecast over network it seems that the menu is for Miracast.